# mod_rewrite URL info required

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to this mod_rewrite.
I have been successfully able to rewrite the URL something like this:
`http://mydomain.com/products/12` to this: `http://mydomain.com/products.php?prodId=12`

But when I give `http://mydomain.com/products/12` in the address bar, the css and js files are not loaded.

But when I access `http://mydomain.com/products.php?prodId=12` the js and css get loaded properly. Please let me know if I am missing something.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9][0-9])/$ /products.php?prodId=$1 [L]
```

My css and js folders are also in the same folder.

Answer (score 6):

You need to know that relative URIs (thus absolute and relative URI paths too) are resolved from a base URI that is – if not explicitly declared – the URI of the current document.

So if you reference external resources from `/products/12` with the relative URI `foo/bar`, it’s resolved to `/products/foo/bar`.

To fix this, use absolute URI paths (beginning with `/`) or absolute URIs (beginning with the protocol) or set explicitly a base URI other than the current (see [`BASE` HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)). But note that changing the base URI has some side effects as it affects *every* relative URI.

Answer (score 4):

You must be using relative links to your script/css files, like this:

```
<script src="my.js"></script>
```

This works for your old URL, but on the new one it will look in the "products" directory, which of course doesn't exist.  You could use absolute urls instead:

```
<script src="/my.js"></script>
```