# Relative paths break in HTML when using mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, relative-path, absolute-path

I am new to `.htaccess` and mod_rewrite.

I am using the following rewrite rules:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^wants/([0-9]+)$ /wantlist.php?wantid=$1
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ /dashboard.php
```

I am able to successfully redirect both the cases.

But in order to do this, I had to change the CSS, JS and other paths to absolute paths without which the CSS and JS did not load.

I was using

```html
<script type="javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

which after the rewrite rule did not work and after I changed it to

```html
<script type="javascript" src="http://example.com/js/javascript.js"></script>
```

I got it to work.

The same is happening for any of the other URLs on the website.

Is there a way to bypass this as I am using relative paths almost everywhere in the site I am developing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an URL resolving issue. See [mod_rewrite URL info required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891775/modrewrite-url-info-required/891785#891785)

You could explicitly set a base URI with the [`BASE` HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE), for example:

```
<base href="/">
```