# Problem using URL rewrite (Relative Paths not working)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, relative-path, absolute-path

I am using a .htccess file in order to rewrite my URLs. I am using the following rules in my .htaccess files

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9+]+)$ /product.php?productid=$1&prodname=$2
```

The rewrite worked fine.

But when i try to access any other page through relative path which is in all the cases, the URL is not getting redirected properly.

Like in the below example

```
<form action "something.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="1" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

When I click on submit, the page that gets loaded is `http://mydomain/product/1/something/something.php` which does not exist and hence throws a 404 error

I tried using the base tag in the head but this creates problem while I am using page anchors and modal windows. It gets redirected to the index page.

Please let me know if further details are required.

I am fairly new to this. So, could someone please help me with this?

Thanks in Advance,
Kartik

Comment: Is it really the whole .htaccess file? If you have access to main apache configuration, you can enable mod_rewrite logging that helps debugging such problems.

Comment: Yes. I have just implemented for one..

Answer (score 3):

This is a URL resolving issue. See [mod_rewrite URL info required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891775/modrewrite-url-info-required/891785#891785) for details.

You can either use absolute URL paths or absolute URLs:

```
<form action="/something.php" method="post">
<form action="http://example.com/something.php" method="post">
```

Or you change the base URL (see [`BASE` HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)) so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL:

```
<base href="/">
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

Answer (score 0):

The short and easy version of solving this is to absolute-path your URLs - /something.php in the form action, not just 'something.php'.