# How to prevent rewriting href attributes when rewriting urls?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

on my web site i want to change url's from (just exemple):

```
site.com/showCategory.php?catId=34
```

to:

```
site.com/category/34/
```

Here is the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^affichage/([0-9]+)$ /affichage/$1/ [R]
    RewriteRule ^affichage/([0-9]+)/$ /affichage.php?n=$1
</IfModule>
```

It works, but the problem is all urls (href tag) in `affichage.php` have "/affichage/29/" and the source for the css file becomes `http://www.site.com/category/34/css/style.css`.

Answer (score 3):

I add this to exclude css and other files I want directly accessible:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(php|ico|png|jpg|gif|css|js|gz|html?)(\W.*)?
```

Or, to exclude by directory name:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/(css|js|static|images)(/.*)
```

Comment: -1 That’s nonsense. The client resolves the relative URLs in the document and not the server.

Comment: It depends on what his issue really is here.  
If he has a common css he needs to include no matter where he is relative to /, this is the way to do it.  That's my most common scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This is a URL resolving issue. You need to use absolute URLs (or at least absolute URL paths) when referencing your external resources. Use the absolute URL path `/css/…` instead of a relative `css/…` or `./css/…`.

Or you change the base URL the relative URLs are resolved from with the [`BASE` HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE). But note that that will affect *all* relative URLs.

See also [Problem using URL rewrite (Relative Paths not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938997/problem-using-url-rewrite-relative-paths-not-working/940178#940178) and [mod_rewrite URL info required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891775/modrewrite-url-info-required/891785#891785).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write the URL out again. However good practice is to wrap it with a function.

e.g.:

```
<a href="<?php rewritefunc('affichage.php',array('n'=>29)); ?>">This URL</a>
<?php
  $do_rewrite = true;

  function rewritefunc($file,$params){
    $ret = '';
    switch(strtolower($file)){
      case 'affichage.php': 
        if($do_rewrite){
          $ret = 'affichage/'.$params['n'].'/';
        }else{
          $ret = 'affichage.php?'.http_build_query($params);
        }
    }
    return $ret;
  }
?>
```

Using the switch statement you can add more url parsing. Also with this wrapper function, you can easily switch between old and new URLs.