# can get this .htaccess file to work for friendly url !

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [L,NC]
```

The problem I am facing is that ;

Lets say I have a URL: `/test.php`. When I visit `/test` it works fine. But when I visit `/test/` it open the page but the CSS and JavaScript file doesn't works and all the images are not displayed.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s a relative URI resolving issue (see [mod_rewrite URL info required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891775/modrewrite-url-info-required/891785#891785) for details).

You’re probably using relative URI paths to reference the external resources. Try to use absolute URI paths (`/foo/bar` instead of `foo/bar` or `./foo/bar`) if possible.